# SQL Server 2019 Linux MSDTC (Centos)

Tags: c#, sql-server, linux, centos7

Hello I have a centos server with SQL Server 2019 , but we are trying to connect a c# app in a windows server 2008 and 2019 and we have this problem:

> "The MSDTC transaction manager was unable to pull the transaction from
>   the source transaction manager due to communication problems. Possible
>   causes are: a firewall is present and it doesn't have an exception for
>   the MSDTC process, the two machines cannot find each other by their
>   NetBIOS names, or the support for network transactions is not enabled
>   for one of the two transaction managers. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8004D02B)"

We haved follow the tutorial to enable the  MSDTC 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-msdtc?view=sql-server-ver15

but the error still showing, also we configured the windows server (where the web page is hosted), granted the Network DTC Access. but the problem persist.

The web app is able to pull information from the databae, but when there is a ditribute transcation, its fails.

Any ideas? Thx in advance.